# Is there a limit to background execution on desktop?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution) there's a limit to how long can background execution be used (`ExtendedExecutionSession`). However, it also seems that some of that page refers exclusively to mobile.

Is there a limit to how long it can run on desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs you linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution) cover desktop scenarios as well as mobile. Search for "desktop" and you'll find information such as:

> **On desktop devices**, extended execution sessions created with
>   ExtendedExecutionReason.Unspecified have a battery-aware time limit.
>   **If the device is connected to wall power, there is no limit to the
>   length of the extended execution time period.** If the device is on 
>   battery power, the extended execution time period can run up to 
>   ten minutes in the background.

The user can choose to ignore the battery limitation on an app-by-app basis.

Comment: Note also that with 1803 (SDK 17134) we are adding a new API that apps can use to prompt the user if they want to ignore the battery saver settings for this app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.background.backgroundexecutionmanager.requestaccesskindasync#Windows_ApplicationModel_Background_BackgroundExecutionManager_RequestAccessKindAsync_Windows_ApplicationModel_Background_BackgroundAccessRequestKind_System_String_

Comment: Thanks. I guess I lost the tree in the forest. Are those 10 minutes additive (i.e. If the app asks for `ExtendedExecutionSession`, uses 9 minutes, disposes, and later asks again, can it run for another 1 minute or 10 minutes?)

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT Thanks. That will be helpful. (BTW The first line in the link doesn't make sense. - It prompts, and it might prompt...)

Comment: The clock starts when your app would get otherwise get suspended. When you dispose the session, or the 10min are up, you get the OnSuspending event. You can't ask for another 'Unspecified' EE session at this point, but you could ask for a 'SavingData' EE session in the OnSuspending event, which will give you up to 5 more minutes.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT Are you saying that the clock is only for one time that the window is minimized, so if the window regains focus and then minimized again the app will be able to run 10 minutes again? If so - that should have been in the docs.

Comment: No, what I am saying is that at the end of the 10min you can't ask for another 10min. The clock restarts every time the app gets minimized.

Comment: Seriuously, how the heck they (API designers) expect developers move their software from a free win32 world to this jail? I don't get it. Not wondering why almost none of the well-known desktop bridge apps are fully converted to UWP after more than a year or so.

Answer (score -1):

No, other than the limit of the parent handle. If the user reboots, or quits the owning Window handle, without specific Persistent Workflow implementations, your background session will stop (and not start again).

You could consider that a Windows Service is a special kind of background task, which has no end.